# Slider bug in ExtJS 6.5

Tags: extjs

I have a tiny [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/23hu), which demonstrates this bug. It shows that if we set default value to a slider field, it fires change event (unlike other standard fields). The code is as simple as:

```
    Ext.create('Ext.slider.Single', {
        width: 200,
        value: 100,
        increment: 10,
        minValue: 0,
        maxValue: 100,
        renderTo: "slider",
        listeners: {
            change: function () {
                console.log("Slider changed!");
            }
        }
    });
    Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Text', {
        width: 200,
        value: "Hello world",
        renderTo: "text",
        listeners: {
            change: function () {
                console.log("Textfield changed!");
            }
        }
    });
```

If you run this code, you will see that slider field fires change event, even though textfield does not fire. BTW in ExtJS 6.2.X there was no such a problem. Now it causes a complete crash to my application. So, there is no compatibility between ExtJS 6.2 and ExtJS 6.5. Wonder, if I can fix it myself.

Comment: BTW. If you have a grid with a slider widget column, then this bug may fire change event dozens of times by default. I've just checked it.

Comment: I have noticed this Jacobian, it fires many times in a sliderwidget, but there does not appear to be a 'changecomplete' event for slider widget any more. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is supposed to be resolved in ExtJS 6.5.1

Please check [link](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?349299)

Basically they have set flag in `initValue` function and in `updateValues` they skip `change` event firing for initialize.

You can override those function from ExtJS 6.5.1 reference.